# $getJSON returns undefined

Tags: php, json, undefined

I am new in this and I was searching a lot for a solution. Here i what I am doing:

```
function getImages(album_id) {

          $.getJSON('get_images.php?album_id=' + album_id,function(data){

          $('#dynamic-content img').html(data.img);
          $('#myModal').modal('show');
      }); }
```

Here I am sure that my parameter `album_id` is filled.
In `get_images.php` I have this code:

```
<?php

require_once 'dbConfig.php';
$img = 'images/c.jpg';

$pdo = Database::connect();
//GET DATA
if(isset($_GET['album_id']))
{
    $img = '';
    $id = $_GET['album_id'];
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE AlbumID = ? ORDER BY GalleryId DESC");
    $stmt->execute(array($id));
    $data = fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($data as $row)
    {    
        $i = "images/" + $row['GalleryName'];   
        $img .= "<img src='$i' class='img-responsive' alt=''/>";
    }      
}
//OUTPUT DATA
Database::disconnect(); 
echo json_encode(array('img'=>$img));
?>
```

When I am trying to debug it in "Firefox Development edition" I can see that return value is "undefined".(function(data))
Please help me. I really do not know what is wrong in my code..

Comment: Why are you returning HTML wrapped in a JSON object? Kind of a pointless wrapper round something the browser can already handle. Just return HTML (use $.get instead of $.getJSON). Quite likely this error will go away at the same time.

Comment: I can think of various reasons to return a json object, where some elements hold static html pieces, and others hold variables to use for further js-mongering. But if ALL you are doing is returning html, then yes, the json object is not needed and do a straight .get or .post.

Comment: Check your browser's dev tools network tab and see what the raw response is for when your ajax calls `get_images.php`. If its not json in the way you expect, you may have leakage from the php script (warnings, errors, notices etc). For example, your php is probably erroring on `$i = "images/" + $row['GalleryName'];`.

Comment: @IncredibleHat point taken, although I'd argue if you're returning data, you should stick to returning data, and let the client-side GUI construct the necessary HTML based on the data, rather than mixing in matching. Seems like a cleaner approach, it's what all the client-side frameworks like Angular, Knockout etc expect to happen. Anyway it's beside the point for this question.

Comment: @ADyson , when I am using $get instead of $getJSON it seems that my modal is showing but it is in black. The idea is to return an array with images in html tags and to show them in modal .Is there any way to see what is going on in "get_images.php" file?

Comment: Being in black could simply be an empty image, or some dodgy CSS, or other things. Yes you can see it - simply watch the Network tab in your browser, see the request to get_images.php and look in the Response tab of that request to see what comes back. If you add extra `echo` statements temporarily into your PHP you can use that to trace the program flow / check the value of variables during the execution.

Comment: @ADyson, thanks a lot. First problem was in get_images.php.Something in the query. Now it returns what I want but I have to figure out why modal is just black window.